# opencv3.1 by uchar to int

Tags: c++11, opencv3.0

I have this code where I have to edit the works of M with 2 values ​​when required .
Mat is a distance given by distancetrasform . If I try to start facciene release me so I do not how I want the value int 2 . I tried to cast but nothing . How do I change the pixel values ​​of M ? with int value ?

```
Mat M = Mat::zeros(300, 300, CV_8U);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < distanza.cols ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < distanza.rows ; j++)
        {
            if ((int)distanza.at<float>(i,j) > 0 )
            {
                M.at <uchar>(i,j) = 2 ;  //here as i write ?
            cout << " " << M.at <uchar>(i, j) << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make M a matrix of integers: `Mat M = Mat::zeros(300, 300, CV_32SC1)`, and access it with: `M.at<int>(i,j)`. However, this code should already work well. Just to be sure, you can use `M.at <uchar>(i,j) = uchar(2);`

Comment: And please, try to be more clear. Your question is almost unreadable